# Bash script to rename files excluding names in array

Tags: bash, awk, sed, rename

I currently have a script where I rename files by removing whitespace and certain names.
This is about 200 names so far so I though an array of names I want to exclude would be a better option.

```
prename -v 's/ /_/g' *

prename -v 's/_-_/_/g' *

prename -v 's/_\(Summer-HD\)//ig' *

prename -v 's/_\(Hammer\)//ig' *

prename -v 's/_\(Hardware-Hybrid\)//g' *

prename -v 's/_\(digital\)//ig' *

prename -v 's/_\(Resolution-SD\)//ig' *
```

This is what i have tried so far, a for loop to iterate over the names I want to exclude and but that has not worked.

```
exclude=('(Summer-HD)' '(Hammer)' '(digital)' '(Resolution-SD)' '(Vacation)' '(Hammer-Hybrid)')

for x in "${exclude[@]}";
    do prename -v 's/$x/_/g' * {} \;
done
```

This for loop does not work at all and just leaves me with a blinking cursor. I'm not sure if I can pass a variable to prename. I modified the for loop a bit on some advise about wrapping things in double quotes.

```
for x in "${exclude[@]}";
    do prename -v 's/$x/_/g' *"$x"* {} \;
done
```

This also does not work, and now I have no idea what all is going on here. I still want to have the array for the names since I currently have more than 200 that i would like to remove. As for prename, I'm not married to the idea, I have heard sed could help or awk. Neither I am comfortable with to do this in. Thanks for any ideas or help provided.

Comment: BTW, it seems you're confusing bash `for` loops with `find` syntax.  `{} \;` is used with `find`'s `-exec` and `-execdir` to pass filename args to the program being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the array (or a scalar variable containing a regex made up from a list) inside the `prename` script - remember that you can use any valid perl code inside a prename script (because a prename script **is** a specialised perl script).  e.g.

```
$ touch foo_\(Summer-HD\)_\(digital\).mkv
$ prename -n 'BEGIN {
                our $exclude=join("|", qw(Summer-HD Hammer digital Resolution-SD Vacation Hammer-Hybrid));
              };

              our $exclude;
              s/_\((?:$exclude)\)//ig;' *
rename(foo_(Summer-HD)_(digital).mkv, foo.mkv)
```

There's a few things worth noting here:

1. Variable scope is very important in a rename script, and the `use strict` pragma is in effect.  See `perldoc strict` (there's a lot more to it but, **tl;dr:** with `strict` you can't use variables you haven't previously declared in the current scope).
2. The `$exclude` variable is defined in a `BEGIN {}` block so that it is only executed ONCE when the script is executed, not once for every filename.  It contains the array joined by `|` characters - i.e. regex alternations.
3. It's defined as an `our` variable so that is shared outside of the BEGIN block, i.e. it's available within the entire scope of the `File::Rename` package.  That's probably more than you care to know, so just think of it as a global variable for the rename script.  The main code block also needs to declare it (with just `our $exclude;`).  See `perldoc -f our`
4. `qw()` is one of perl's quoting operators, which turns a list of whitespace-separated bare words into an array.  See `perldoc -f qw`.  BTW, in perl, "array" and "list" are almost synonyms - see `perldoc -q difference.*list.*array`

Also worth noting is that instead of running `rename` multiple times, you should run it once with a longer script (or with multiple `-e '...script...'` options).  e.g.

```
$ prename -n 'BEGIN {
                our $exclude=join("|", qw(Summer-HD Hammer digital Resolution-SD Vacation Hammer-Hybrid));
              };

              our $exclude;

              s/ /_/g;
              s/_-_/_/g;
              s/_\((?:$exclude)\)//ig;' *
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
exclude=(
  '(Summer-HD)'
  '(Hammer)'
  '(digital)'
  '(Resolution-SD)'
  '(Vacation)'
  '(Hammer-Hybrid)'
)

pattern="_(${(j[|])${(b@)exclude}})"

autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '*' '${f//$~pattern}'
```

Where `${(b)exclude}` escapes the glob operators in the elements of `$exclude`, `${(j[|])...}` joins the result with `|`, so we end up with `$pattern` being `_(exclude1|exclude2...)` (specifically: `_(\(Summer-HD\)|\(Hammer\)|\(digital\)|\(Resolution-SD\)|\(Vacation\)|\(Hammer-Hybrid\))`), and matches of that are replaced with nothing using the `${f//pattern[/replacement]}` operator from ksh93 inside the `zmv` batch renamer.